# Syntax error: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, ide

```
 File "/home/867adbb593efa0da0476219a7f34fa60.py", line 37
|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split()
                                   ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Im not sure why this small block isnt working, trying to use tweeter here and when I test the code thats given in their own IDE this comes up, I have already fixed numerous small issues but I cannot understand this one.  Please stack gods, help this peasant.

Edit: as is looks to be missing something form the beginning of the block, here is the full block for context: `return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]")
                                    |(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split()`

Comment: The first half of your line seems to be missing. Is it really surprising that it throws a syntax error?

Comment: I edited the block for context

Comment: No quote at the front of the first string in the list

Comment: and an extra close paren

Comment: Thank you, always something a second pair of eyes can do